# How to determine what hardware is associated with what network interface

Tags: networking, command-line, networkmanager, hostapd

I have an inbuilt network card and a Wi-Fi dongle.

I use `wpa_supplicant`, `hostapd` and the likes to operate them.

The trouble is that sometimes the dongle is `wlan0`, and sometimes it is `wlan1` (likewise for the inbuilt network card of course): so I never know whether "`wlan0`" is the dongle or the inbuilt card. The association `wlanX` <-> hardware appears completely random to me.

**What is the command line to see, for a specific interface (`wlan0` for instance), what hardware it corresponds to?**

**Alternatively, how to make sure a specific hardware (the dongle say) is always designated by a same interface (`wlan0` say)?**

Not being able to discriminate between these two hardware is a real problem because my dongle does not support the AP mode for instance.

Comment: This solved it for me (on Raspbian Stretch): https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=198946. More tricky that it seems.

Answer (score 1):

The device names are "unstable" since the numbers are assigned on boot based on whichever device answers first during enumeration. As you observed, depending on the hardware set-up, this may be random.

You should consider enabling systemd's [persistent network interfaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/141227/how-to-enable-predictable-network-interface-names). Alternatively, you can manually configure udev to assign a custom device name via
[70-persistent-net.rules](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110496/cloned-linux-system-and-etc-udev-rules-d-70-persistent-net-rules)

As for configuring the network itself, [using netplan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485395/cant-permanently-assign-additional-ip-addresses-to-usb-ethernet-adapter-via-et) may (in case you use Ubuntu 17.04 or newer) applicable, too. The access point's interface is usually either part of a bridge (network level 2) or statically configured (network level 3,  client's data needs to be routed). According to the [examples](https://netplan.io/examples), a static configuration with netplan looks like this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp2s0b1:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.1/24]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explicit the last paragraph please?

Comment: @hartmut Yes. I extended the answer. Please note that I did not test this exact configuration myself.